# dreamweaver CS5 code formatter

Tags: dreamweaver

I couldn't find, is there any code formatter (code beautier) shortcut or button or extension for Dreamweaver CS5 ?

Comment: Similar to [How to make code neater in Dreamweaver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340396/how-to-make-code-neater-in-dreamweaver?lq=1) and [Dreamweaver CS5 Auto-Format source code like in VS2010 CTRL+K, CTRL+D?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078082/dreamweaver-cs5-auto-format-source-code-like-in-vs2010-ctrlk-ctrld)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it in Command/ Apply Source Formatting ?

I guess it depends what exactly you are trying to format, too  - but you didn't mention that :)

Answer (score 5):

In Windows Environment : "Alt + C + A".

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined shortcut key, but you can define a short cut via

**Main Menu > Edit > Keyboard ShortCuts...**

(I'm not sure for CS5, I've experienced this case for CS6)

Answer (score 1):

Open Dreamweaver than you go to top bar > menu > commands > Apply Source Formatting after click on Apply Source Formatting your code format Done.

I hope help for you :)