# Dreamweaver CS5 Auto-Format source code like in VS2010 CTRL+K, CTRL+D?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dreamweaver, autoformatting

Does Dreamweaver CS5 support auto-formatting feature similar to Visual Studio 2010 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it does. I don't think there is a keyboard shortcut for it, and I don't know how to make one if that is possible, but the auto-formatting is at Commands > Apply Source Formatting.

I hope that helps.

Comment: About time someone answered my question! Thank you Hristo.

Comment: Yeah of course! Now... do you want to answer my question? I was searching for an answer as to whether you can do auto-formatting in Visual Studio 2010 as you do it in Dreamweaver CS5, and I stumbled to your question... but CTRL+K doesn't work, or any combo of that.

Comment: Dreamweaver CS5 does a good job with PHP code too adding breaks in includes etc.. was pretty impressed with this.

Comment: @Hristo: For Visual Studio CTRL-K-D. In other words, while continuing to hold down the CTRL key, press K, release, then press D.

Answer (score 2):

Dreamweaver doesn't actually support auto code format where actually it needed. auto formatting works just on HTML, CSS... but not work for javascript, php etc.

Answer (score 2):

Dreamweaver does support auto formatting. The commands menu offers a lot of features like spell check, recording, cleaning up html and, what we want, source formatting.

The only problem, is that by default Dreamweaver does not have a shortcut key for it. But this problem can be easily solved by defining a shortcut key of your choice.

Goto Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts

There are multiple sets of shortcut profiles, it is recommended to create one by duplicating one of the existing and naming it for future reference.

Once you do that, you can select Commands >  Apply Source Formatting and assign a shortcut key to it.

A common issue is that most of the keys are already assigned to other options. I'm personally using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as its not used by any other shortcut and is easier but you an chose any you like.

You can also define one for "Apply Source Formatting for Selection" which comes very handy.

Alternatively, you can also make keyboard shortcuts manually by editing the menus.xml

Answer (score 1):

there is no shortcut but we can do a little workaround <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> than <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your own shortcut key for code formatting in Dreamweaver CS5. 
See 'Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts'; under the 'Commands' menu click 'Apply Source Formatting' and assign your custom keyboard shortcut. If the given shortcut is already assigned it will alert you.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will work to apply Auto Format Source Code. It's not a defined shortcut.
<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for the commands menu and <kbd>C</kbd> for Apply Source Formatting.

Hope this will be helpful for you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> . This worked for me in dreamviewer 6